# MySQL: Get the values from different tables in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where 3 columns correspond to an ID in another table, what I need is in one query to get the actual values of that ID in the other table, all in one query.

I'm having troubles figuring out the SQL to get the result what I want. I've tried with subqueries and join, but can't seem to figure it out.

This are the tables:

**Table A**

```
+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| id       | int(3)      |
| name     | text        |
| item1    | int(3)      |
| item2    | int(3)      |
| item3    | int(3)      |
+----------+-------------+
```

**Table B**

```
+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| id       | int(3)      |
| name     | text        |
| url      | text        |
+----------+-------------+
```

In Table A the fields item1, item2 and item3 are IDs from Table B.

I need to get the result of a query to Table A and get the actual values of item1, item2 and item3 in one single query, not the ID numbers.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

BTW, this will be used in a PHP App, don't know if this information is relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the relation between the tables?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BfofgkrI3Y

Comment: Good one @JackWilliams

Comment: @iamsleepy: The relation is there, Table A: item1, item2 and item3 correspond to an ID in Table B.

Comment: @JackWilliams i'll check that video right now, i've been trying to use JOIN but couldn't make it work, I can get the url and name from  item1, but as far as item2 and item3 concerns i can't manage to make it work, i'll watch that video. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean by relation was, is `tableA` `id` field equals to `tableB` `id` field ? And it looks like you have duplicate `name` field

Comment: @iamsleepy: No. `item1`, `item2` and `item3` from `tableA` correspond to an `id` in `tableB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a join.

```
Select * from TableA a, TableB b1, TableB b2, TableB b3
where a.item1 = b1.id
and a.item2 = b2.id
and a.item3 = b3.id
```

Comment: Well, looks so simple now, I guess I was complicating myself with joins, unions and subqueries.. Thanks @Thomas.

Comment: You'd use a UNION if were selecting the same columns from >1 table. There's a video for that too, [take a look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crj8x1PevcY).